# Expose Hue with Component Gateway for Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Is it possible to expose Hue with Component Gateway for Dataproc? I went through the docs and didn't find any option to add service to it. I am creating Dataproc cluster with below command.

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create hive-cluster \
    --scopes sql-admin,bigquery \
    --image-version 1.5 \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
    --num-masters 1 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --num-workers 2 \
    --region $REGION \
    --zone $ZONE \
    --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
    --initialization-actions gs://bucket/init-scripts/cloud-sql-proxy.sh,gs://bucket/init-scripts/hue.sh \
    --properties hive:hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=gs://$PROJECT-warehouse/datasets,dataproc:jupyter.notebook.gcs.dir=gs://bucket/notebooks/jupyter \
    --metadata "hive-metastore-instance=$PROJECT:$REGION:hive-metastore" \
    --enable-component-gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

Hue is not an optional component of Dataproc, hence not accessible from component gateway. For now, you have to use Dataproc web interfaces:

> Once the cluster has been created, Hue is configured to run on port 8888 on the master node in a Dataproc cluster. To connect to the Hue web interface, you will need to create an SSH tunnel and use a SOCKS 5 Proxy with your web browser as described in the [dataproc web interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces) documentation. In the opened web browser go to 'localhost:8888' and you should see the Hue UI.